# 422 Unprocessable Entity when posting to Laravel

Tags: c#, android, rest, restsharp, maui

I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Response is showing me Content-Type: application/json instead of multipart/form-data....

did anyone know what i need to do?

I build in .net 6 MAUI, Android 12 and RestSharp as http client

Please give a look on this image:
[(IMAGE)  Response StatusCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r06db.png)

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest(PostImageUrl, Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddFile("image", bauzeichnung);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Everything is tested with Postman and works like expected.

**EDIT**
also tried:

```
 request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
```

Is this Directory Path correct?
"/data/user/0/com.Lippert.Digital/cache/b81fe7a766a64981918f1012d7865c8c.jpg"

Can AddFile work with this type of path from my Android phone?
This picture was taken with **MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();**

[(IMAGE) Directory Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpTY1.png)

**EDIT**

**PHP Controller**

```
    public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image'     => 'file',
    ]);

    
    if ($request->file('image')) 
    {
        $name = time().$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('image')->move('Bauzeichnungen',$name);

        $image = url('Bauzeichnungen/'.$name);
        
    }else
    {   
        $image = 'Image not found';
       
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    DB::table('Bauzeichnung')->insert([  
        'image' => "$image",
        'erstellt_von' => 26,
        'aktualisiert_von' => 26,
        'Zeitstempel' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ]);
    
}
```

**PHP Route**

```
Route::post('/uploadImage','ImageController@uploadImage');
```

Comment: Have you tried using "request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true"? Normally, if you add a file by default, it should change your header to "multipart/form-data" ( https://restsharp.dev/usage#uploading-files )

Comment: "Response is showing me" - is the issue with the request or the response?

Comment: Response only gives me the response to my request. I can't say where the problem is because it shouldn't be a problem. I see that you are more experienced in Xamarin. How do you post a picture that was previously taken by an Android camera? It's not clear to me what could be the reason. I give the current path of my image, exactly the same as I do with Postman and still this message appears.

Comment: "still this message appears" - what message are you talking about?

Comment: i mean the Response message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r06db.png makes for me no sense why this happens. in Postman i have set one Key to file and named it "image" and Value is the Image Path.. and in C# i have exactly the same. But here Response say to me this what you can see in the image i posted here. "Unprocessable Entity"...

Comment: please DO NOT post errors as images.  The fact that you are getting a specific HTTP response error is something that should be mentioned prominently in your post, not buried in a screenshot.  What kind of server is this?  Have you done any investigation of what that response code means or why your server code would return it?

Comment: I have a Hetzner Server (Debian) running Lumen (Laravel) latest version. i didnt found any much about this error in combination with my case (post addfile). i edit my Thread and add also my php controller if this helps.

Comment: I get a huge number of hits on https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+422+unprocessable+entity.  I'd suggest your figure out how to log the raw request received by the server and compare the Postman request and the Restsharp one to see how they differ

Comment: And I would also edit your question and title to prominently mention the 422 error.  Why you think this is related to "RestSharp content-type" is beyond me.

Comment: Because Response writes "Content-Type: Application/json" that the reason why i think my content type is the problem. it could set to "multipart/form-data" and "image/jpeg"

Comment: you are getting an error from the server, why would the type of the **response** have any bearing on this?  When you use Postman what is the response type?

Comment: @Jason unbelieveable  thanks, you give me the important spot. I log both and saw that my Android images was to big. i edited now my php.ini and increased post_max_size,
upload_max_filesize and memory_limit.. now everything works. thanks for this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **422 Unprocessable Entity - Solution**

After couple of days i found the Solution for the error above...

---

****The reason for that:****

*Images are too big and only smaller values were allowed in php.ini.*

---

**How it can be solved:**

1. open your **php.ini**  - (location: /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini)

---

2. set **memory_limit =** (i set to **-1**)

Sets the maximum amount of memory, in bytes, that a script can use. This can be used to prevent badly written scripts from "eating up" all of the available memory on a server. **To set no memory limit, set this directive to the value -1.**

---

3. Set **post_max_size =** (i set to **128M**)

Sets the maximum allowed size of POST data. This option also affects file upload. To upload larger files, the value must be greater than **upload_max_filesize** . In general, **memory_limit** should be greater than **post_max_size**. If an int value is used, that value is measured in bytes. You can also use the shorthand form as described in this FAQ . If the size of the POST data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals become to be empty. This can be tracked in a number of ways, e.g. B. by passing the $_GET variable to the script that processes the data, ie and then checking if $_GET['processed'] is set.

---

4. Set **upload_max_filesize =** (i set to **64M**)

The maximum size that an uploaded file can have.

---

Where i got the Information - PHP Manual:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php

Big thanks to : @Jason

Answer (score 0):

Directory Path is not correct, this path is belong to your cache storage. When you upload an image, image is writing your cache and when you post is, you are posting your image in cache. And when you try to take path, it giving cache path to you.

Comment: Ah okey but how should i do it? I take a screenshot which is in cache, then i want to post it to my WebServer. Which URL i should use? i only have the LocalPath to upload it.. when i post it with Postman i also can use my localpath successfull, so why Android should be differend? This should be only a path to a image. With the same path i can display the image on my App, so why i cannot post it?

Comment: you should post image and save it in server. In server side you can take all informations about your image.

You should take the image and store it in your machine(Local or Server). Then tahe the path of image and save database as Url(If you don't know the difference between url and path, you should research it). When you send image just send the url of your image

Comment: This is exact what i do. i take a Photo and want to post it. It already works with Postman. i put in the local path from the image and it posts the 'Whole' image to my webserver (public folder) and insert the image url from Webserver directory to my Database with some other informations like current timestamp and updated_by... look here my database: https://gyazo.com/633352f0859ec809dcad2b868ac8b655 This works already and now i want to bring my Android App to do this too instead of only postman. i want to use exact the same function from postman to Android in MAUI

Comment: and bcs of you said 'you should post image and save it in server.' - this is what i try to do. nothing more ^^ My problem is that i cannot post the image to my server while i using C# for some reasons.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image

Check your serverside code with this pls,

Comment: In RestRequest, the first argument have to be a string and cannot be Method.Post at first place. https://gyazo.com/5070de5bd670d84e4d4603ac5a15041e